# Xcode Beta hangs often / SourceKitService high cpu

Tags: xcode, swift

In some of my new projects, I have the problem, that Xcode Beta5 (I had this problem with earlier betas too) really often hangs ('beachball'). In the activity monitor I can see, that SourceKitService needs 100 % of the CPU. 
Xcode than hangs for at least 10-15 seconds.

I don't know, if it's a problem with my code. In the Console Utility I can see a lot of this error:

`sourcekit-serv[63558]: [1:getBufferStamp:17199:1776.3650] failed to stat file: <imports> (No such file or directory)`

UPDATE:

I found out, that working with the following is the problem: `[[String: AnyObject]]`, just like:

```
var myArray: [[String: AnyObject]]
myArray = [
    ["name": "item1", "children": [
        "name": "child1", "children": [],
        "name": "child2", "children": []]],
    ["name": "item2", "children": [
        "name": "child1", "children": [],
        "name": "child2", "children": []]]  
]
```

But CAUTION: This code completely blocks Xcode after a few seconds!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the beta. Please [file a bug report to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/). Make sure to sample the app from activity monitor while it's spinning and attach the sample. You can also start a thread on [Apple's Developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/) to see if the Apple developers have any suggestions.

Comment: Seconded that it's a bug, however I often find that it is something in the code which causes the Source Kit Service to go wrong - so it is always worth just double checking everything.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Even the `system.log` issues errors: `sourcekit-serv[90283]: [1:getBufferStamp:7735:72.0411] failed to stat file: <imports> (No such file or directory)` I couldn't yet figure out what file/codeblock/line/import/whatever is causing this.

Answer (score 10):

After struggling with this for a while and reading many posts by people struggling with the same issue, I realized that the meta theme is: Swift struggles with "complicated" arrays and dictionaries.  In order to help Xcode I explicitly defined the type of variable for all of my arrays and dictionaries instead of letting Xcode figure it out.  This made my problems go away.

Instead of letting Swift figure out the type of variable by writing the following line of code:

```
var myDictionary1 = ["Item":[1,2,3],"Thing":[4,5,6],"Weight":[7,8,9]]
```

I rewrote my variable declarations as follows:

```
var myDictionary2: [String:[Int]] = ["Item":[1,2,3],"Thing":[4,5,6],"Weight":[7,8,9]]
```

As a side note, Xcode's autocompletion shows myDictionary1 as [String:ArrayInt] and myDictionary2 as [String:[Int]].

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Clearing DerivedData did not help. This is still an issue on Xcode 7.1. I have found dictionaries do not need to be complicated for this to happen. It seems best at this point to always declare the types of the keys and values e.g. var myDictionary: [String: AnyObject]

Answer (score 9):

I have found that when SourceKit is misbehaving, and I can verify that the problem is *not* with my code (causing the compiler to crash behind the scenes), that quitting Xcode, deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache and also the folder in that same location with the derived data for my app often (at least temporarily) fixes the problem.

Comment: I tried this.  It did not work at all.  The next time I opened Xcode, it still did it.  It seems to be related to not initializing variables in some cases.

Comment: I can almost always get an error like this by adding a line with a lot of variables on it, like this: 'if ((bax * bcy * bdz + bay * bcz * bdx + baz * bcx * bdy - baz * bcy * bdx - bay * bcx * bdz - bax * bcz * bdy)
                        * (bpx * bcy * bdz + bpy * bcz * bdx + bpz * bcx * bdy - bpz * bcy * bdx - bpy * bcx * bdz - bpx * bcz * bdy) > 0.0)'

Comment: I'm sure you can do lots of edge-casey stuff that borks the compiler, but my code is module-heavy (I'm writing frameworks and the code that uses them) so my crashes and my fix are probably not applicable to your particular situation.

Comment: When the Console log for the SourceKitService crash contains "clang::CompilerInstance::loadModule", this method seems to fix the problem. Thanks!